# Winding number property

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, and assume there are functions $r:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma(t)=r(t)\exp(i\phi(t)).$ Prove that $Ind_\gamma(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}(\phi(1)-\phi(0))$. And if $\gamma$ is a differentiable function then also $r$ and $\phi$ are differentiable, therefore $Ind_\gamma(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1 \frac{\gamma '(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt.$

The first part seems slightly similar to the mean value theorem.

I have the following theorems

> Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ be a closed curve and $p\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\exp (p)=\gamma(0)$. Then there is a curve $\tilde{\gamma}$ such that $\gamma=\exp \circ \gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(0)=p.$

Also

> For $\gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}$ as before, is $Ind_\gamma (0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\tilde{\gamma}(1)-\tilde{\gamma}(0))$.

Now it seems that it makes sense to consider $\tilde{\gamma} = i\phi$ and IF we had $\gamma(t)=\exp(\tilde{\gamma} (t))$ then $Ind_\gamma (0)= \frac{1}{2\pi i}(i\phi(1)-i\phi(0))=\frac{1}{2\pi}(\phi(1)-\phi(0))$, except that it is not $\gamma(t)=\exp(\tilde{\gamma} (t))$ but $\gamma(t)=r(t)\exp(\tilde{\gamma} (t))$.

I don't see how exactly the $r$ function vanishes, nor do I see how the integral expresion follows.

Comment: $r$ is always positive. Homotopize it to constant equal to 1.

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\gamma'}{\gamma}=\int_{a}^{b}\tilde{\gamma}'=\tilde{\gamma}(b)-\tilde{\gamma}(a)$ if $\gamma=\exp(\tilde{\gamma})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct calculation (your turn !) gives :

$Ind_\gamma(0)= \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z} dz= ....$

$=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int _0^1 (\frac{r'(t)}{r(t)}+i \phi'(t))dt=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}(\log(r(1))-\log(r(0))+i(\phi(1)-\phi(0)))$.

Since $\gamma $ is closed,

$r(0)=|\gamma(0)|=|\gamma(1)|=r(1)$,

and the result follws.